# Pattern for Nuget Package (Abstractions, DepedencyInjections, etc.)

Tags: design, architectural-patterns, libraries, patterns-and-practices, nuget

I've been interested in following what other successful libraries are doing with their nuget packages. Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any materials to read online and I don't even know what to search for.

What I'm referring to is how a nuget package can be broken down into something like this:

- CompanyName
- CompanyName.Core
- CompanyName.Abstractions
- CompanyName.DependencyInjections
- CompanyName.{Feature}
- Etc.

I kind of get the basic idea by just snooping around public repos on github but I wanted to read more about this. I know you'd generally make a separate project for feature related codes or common codes but what I currently don't quite get is the Abstractions and DependencyInjections. I know it's there to make it easier and flexible for the consumer but how exactly?

**For Abstractions**:

1. Do I literally pull out all my interfaces and abstract classes and put it here?
2. Where do I draw the line?

**For DependencyInjections**:

1. Do all my `IServiceCollection` extensions live here?
2. How would the consumer utilize this DependencyInjection? In my experience, I very seldom install both the main nuget package and DepedendencyInjections package. Most of the time, the main package is enough.

I would really appreciate if you can shed some light on this or better yet, give some reading materials I could read.

Thank you!

Comment: This isn't as standardized as you might think. To be honest, I've never dealt with a NuGet package that had "abstractions" and "dependency injections" sub-packages. I don't think any of us can give you an authoritative answer. Only the maintainers of those NuGet packages can answer your question.

Comment: Well-established libraries are often split across packages to help with legacy .NET Framework projects using ancient versions of MSBuild/NuGet, where dependency management had traditionally been a major pain point. Library authors had to be careful only to depend on other packages that they **really** needed because larger projects could find themselves in "DLL Hell" with conflicting dependency versions from different libraries.  The Modern NuGet/MSBuild/.NET ecosystem has made most of these problems go away so there's often no reason to split libraries across a lot of packages any more.